# Multistrip to single strip tiff using Commons Imaging

Tags: java, tiff, imaging

I am trying to convert a multi strip Tiff image to a single strip tiff. I was able to do so using JAI APIs from Java. But these are not platform independent.
I am now working with Commons Imaging to perform this task. Here i am not able to find how exactly i can write back the single strip image data.

Here is the code snippet that i have written so far. (Please note this is just a crude example and i will modify the code prior getting single strip)

```
//get the metadata out a tiff file
final IImageMetadata metadata = Imaging.getMetadata(file);
iffImageMetadata tiffMetadata = null;

if(metadata instanceof TiffImageMetadata){
    tiffMetadata = (TiffImageMetadata) metadata;
    TiffImageMetadata.Directory dir = (TiffImageMetadata.Directory)tiffMetadata.getDirectories().get(0);

TiffImageData imgData = dir.getTiffImageData();
long offset = 0;

//check number of strips(can be done by getting TIFF TAG 273
DataElement[] imgDataElements = imgData.getImageData();
int noOfSTrips = imgDataElements.length;

if(noOfSTrips == 1){
    return; //already a single strip
}

//merge all single strips to a single byte array 
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );

for(int i = 0; i< noOfSTrips; i++){
    ByteSourceData data = (ByteSourceData) imgDataElements[i];
    outputStream.write(data.getData());
}

List<TiffField> tiffFields = tiffMetadata.getAllFields();
TiffOutputField outputField = null;

for(TiffField tiffField : tiffFields){
    String type = tiffField.getFieldTypeName();
    switch(tiffField.getTag())  {
    case 273:
        if (type == FieldType.LONG.getName())
        {
            if (tiffField.getCount() > 1){
                //this will be writen back to the output set
                outputField = new TiffOutputField(tiffField.getTagInfo(), tiffField.getFieldType(), 1, outputStream.toByteArray());
                offset = tiffField.getByteArrayValue()[0];
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

TiffOutputSet outputSet = tiffMetadata.getOutputSet();
List<TiffOutputDirectory> outputDirectories = outputSet.getDirectories();
TiffOutputDirectory outputDir = outputDirectories.get(0);
outputDir.removeField(273);

outputDir.add(outputField);

//NOW WHAT TO DO??
//I HAVE SEEN ExifRewritter CLASS THAT CAN UPDATE TIFF WITH EXIF, BUT HOW I CAN UPDATE THIS BACK
```

}

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: What is your current code that's not working? Code examples are very helpful.

Comment: Is the writer writing striped TIFFs by default? Have you tried simply setting the `TIFF_TAG_ROWS_PER_STRIP` value to `-1`, or the pixel height of your image?

Comment: @haraldK i have added a sample code, since the TiffImageMetadata is immutable in nature i can't modify its property. Please let me know what you think of this.

Comment: I don't think just splicing the strips together without decoding/re-encoding will work in general (it probably will for chunky, uncompressed files). But I'm no expert on Commons Imaging, unfortunately. Have you tried reading (decoding)  the TIFF before rewriting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i was finally able to convert a Multistrip tif image to single strip. 
Basically i had copied some code from `TiffImageWriterBase` class of Commons Imaging, thats due to the reason that `rowsPerStrip` was being calculated in such a way that the resulting image was always a Multistrip. . I had modified this code to set the `rowsPerStrip = image.height`. 
Here is the code that i have written:

```
//source is any multistrip image
File file = new File("D:\\Tiff\\image.tif");
BufferedImage src = Imaging.getBufferedImage(file);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Tiff\\modified_image.tif"));
os = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
final int width = src.getWidth();
final int height = src.getHeight();
//These are set as per CCITT 4 compression, you can modify these as per requirement
int samplesPerPixel = 1;
int bitsPerSample = 1;
int photometricInterpretation =0;
//setting rowsPerStrip equal to heigh of the image, this did the trick for me
int rowsPerStrip = height;//This code was present originally -> stripSizeInBits / (1 * bitsPerSample * samplesPerPixel);
rowsPerStrip = Math.max(1, rowsPerStrip); // must have at least one.
//you can copy getStrips method from TiffImageWriterBase class or work upon yours own
final byte[][] strips = getStrips(src, samplesPerPixel, bitsPerSample, rowsPerStrip);
for (int i = 0; i < strips.length; i++) {
    strips[i] = T4AndT6Compression.compressT6(strips[i], width,
            strips[i].length / ((width + 7) / 8));
}
final TiffElement.DataElement[] imageData = new TiffElement.DataElement[strips.length];
for (int i = 0; i < strips.length; i++) {
    imageData[i] = new TiffImageData.Data(0, strips[i].length, strips[i]);
}
final TiffOutputSet outputSet = new TiffOutputSet(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
final TiffOutputDirectory directory = outputSet.addRootDirectory();
directory.add(TiffTagConstants.TIFF_TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH, width);
directory.add(TiffTagConstants.TIFF_TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH, height);
directory.add(TiffTagConstants.TIFF_TAG_PHOTOMETRIC_INTERPRETATION,
        (short) photometricInterpretation);
directory.add(TiffTagConstants.TIFF_TAG_COMPRESSION,
        (short) TiffConstants.TIFF_COMPRESSION_CCITT_GROUP_4);
directory.add(TiffTagConstants.TIFF_TAG_SAMPLES_PER_PIXEL,
        (short) samplesPerPixel);
directory.add(TiffTagConstants.TIFF_TAG_BITS_PER_SAMPLE,
        (short) bitsPerSample);
directory.add(TiffTagConstants.TIFF_TAG_ROWS_PER_STRIP,
        rowsPerStrip);
directory.add(TiffTagConstants.TIFF_TAG_RESOLUTION_UNIT,
        (short) 2);
PixelDensity pixelDensity = PixelDensity.createFromPixelsPerInch(72, 72);
directory.add(TiffTagConstants.TIFF_TAG_XRESOLUTION,
        RationalNumber.valueOf(pixelDensity.horizontalDensityInches()));
directory.add(TiffTagConstants.TIFF_TAG_YRESOLUTION,
        RationalNumber.valueOf(pixelDensity.verticalDensityInches()));
final TiffImageData tiffImageData = new TiffImageData.Strips(imageData,
        rowsPerStrip);
directory.setTiffImageData(tiffImageData);
//single strip image will be written to output stream
new TiffImageWriterLossy().write(os, outputSet);
```